# Working with javascript prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype-chain

Why does this work....

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
  }


Person.prototype.speak =  function() {
   alert(this.name);
}


var person = new Person("fred");

person.speak();
```

But not this..

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
        speak =  function() {
   alert(this.name);
}


var person = new Person("fred");

person.speak();
```

I am not understanding how inheritance works, or the javascript "prototype-chain".

Thanks.

Comment: read this. http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: If you indent the code properly, it should be easier to spot the mistake

Comment: *'I am not understanding how inheritance works, or the javascript "prototype-chain".'* That's a very good position you're in. You just have to start some reading. This question has been answered countless times on this site alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
        speak =  function() {
   alert(this.name);
}
```

should be

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.speak = function () {
      alert(this.name);
   };
}
```

Comment: Ahh, OP was creating a global speak function instead of attaching it to `this`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's variable scope that you're not understanding.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;

  speak = function() {
    alert(this.name);
  }
}
```

By omitting `var` before `speak = ...` here you've created a global variable named `speak`, not a variable within `Person`'s scope. In a browser global variables are attached to the global object, `window`, so your code is equivalent to:

```
function Person( name ) {
  this.name = name;

  window.speak = function() { alert( this.name ); }
```

}

Douglas Crockford has written [some related material](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) about variable scope in prototypal inheritance that you should find enlightening.

Comment: That's not really equivalent, the function will be assigned to `window.speak` every time `Person` is invoked. And it will be different function object every time as well.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "roughly equivalent." It was meant to be illustrative. Nevertheless I have changed the code.

Comment: @Jordan you're right about him creating a global but the problem here is failing to assign `speak()` to `this`. Using `var` would make it a private method of `Person` and so he would not be able to access it like he wants to with `person.speak();`.